# Install4j Check JDBC Connection Action SetDriver

Tags: install4j

In Install4j i call the CheckJdbcConnectionAction action and execute it.
But it dont works.
here is the code:

```
    CheckJdbcConnectionAction checkConnection = new CheckJdbcConnectionAction();
    checkConnection.setDriverClassName("org.postgres.Driver");
```

here is the log:

```
    [ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.jdbc.CheckJdbcConnectionAction: Driver class org.postgres.Driver was not found. Add the JAR file to the "Installer->Custom code & resources" step.
```

I added the jar (postgresql-42.2.0.jre7.jar) into "Installer->Custom code & resources" but it still gives me the same error.

I changed the Value of setDriverClassName to postgresql-42.2.0.jre7 but still the same error

Whats the next step to get it work?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver class name is wrong, it should be `org.postgresql.Driver`.

Also, if you really want to execute this action programmatically, you have to set the properties `setJdbcUrl(...)`, `setUser(...)` and `setPassword(...)` as well.